# How to Fill one cell based off how many blank cells there are

Tags: if-statement

I need one value if one cell is empty, a different value if there are 2 empty cells, a 3rd value if 3 cells are empty ect etc up to 10 different values

Comment: Can you please tag this with what language or program you are using? Is this Excel? or google sheets?

Comment: I added the tag. This is excel